# Which action brought up view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

From a view, is it possible to know which action led to the displaying of that view or if not, how do I get the last part of the path of the url (which will be the action name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
```

You can also get this from `@Url.RequestContext.RouteData` object:

```
@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```